# Getting an IP for whitelisting from a multi-node GCP kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, kubernetes

I have access to a service (Kafka broker) in our enterprise network that is accessible via the VPN or select whitelisted IPs. I can connect via kafkacat locally (on the vpn or in the office) but not inside GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I get a generic error message "Broker Transport Fail" both in GCP and locally if I'm not on the VPN.

Everything we're running in GCP is cluster (Kubernetes) based, on multiple nodes and potentially multiple clusters. Is there an ideal pattern or a tried and true way to have GCP provision us a single outgoing IP that we can use across all nodes in a given cluster for whitelisting purposes, such that when I access a basic service on the WAN, by default it will go through this IP and be acceptable to the org?

Otherwise I guess we could get multiple IPs at the Node level (if that's where they indeed live) as long as they are static.

It seems that each worker node has a different external IP. I've seen documentation on setting up an IP with a GCP VM but we are not using VMs.

I'm sure others have run into this problem, such that there must be a convenient solution.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use [GKE private with Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example). As the GKE nodes have private IP address, the egress traffic will go through Cloud NAT. You have to provision Cloud NAT with static IPs, as opposed to the example link which uses auto-allocated IPs.

If you can't use private GKE clusters for valid reasons, then you can try tools like [kubeip](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip) to assign static external IPs to your GKE nodes.